# Converting XYZ tile request to WMS request?

Tags: arcgis-server, wms, cache

I am wondering if it is possible to convert XYZ layer request
e.g
(http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/XYZ-js.html)

to a regular WMS request? (Basically if it is possible to convert the numbers Z/X/Y to a bounding box)

I have a working WMS on the server side that can return the needed tiles, if the convertion is possible then I would convert the Z/X/Y on the server side and pass it to my WMS service to get the tile.

I need this because I have an Arcgis generated cache and it would be nice to also support the XYZ standart for the same cache.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your actual question. DO you want to convert from XYZ tile request to bounding box for WMS? or do you want to convert from XYZ tile request to ArcGIS Server's cache System of ZXY?

Comment: I want to convert from XYZ tile request to bounding box for WMS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best reference for this is [this page on the OSM Wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames). It has Pseudo code as well as code in various languages for converting from the XYZ tilenames, to the bounding box.

The Pseudocode for this is as follows

```
n = 2 ^ zoom
lon_deg = xtile / n * 360.0 - 180.0
lat_rad = arctan(sinh(π * (1 - 2 * ytile / n)))
lat_deg = lat_rad * 180.0 / π
```

Note that this gives you the coordinate for the NW-corner of the square. Use the function with xtile+1 and ytile+1 to get the SE-corner

Comment: Tested with one tile and looks like it is working, thanks again!